# Autoencoders: Papers and Books regarding algorithms for Training

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder

Which are some of the famous research papers and/or books which concern Autoencoders and the various different training algorithms for Autoencoders?
I'm talking about research papers and/or books which lay the foundation for the different training algorithms used to train autoencoders.

Answer (score 0):

I first saw autoencoders in Fahlman's 1988 article where he introduces quickpropagation for their training.  The paper is here.

Fahlman, S.  E.  (1988) "Faster-Learning Variations on Back-Propagation: An Empirical Study" in Proceedings, 1988 Connectionist Models Summer School, Morgan-Kaufmann, Los Altos CA.  (This paper introduced the Quickprop learning algorithm.)

I also wrote the following example around it, including quickprop.

https://github.com/encog/encog-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encog/examples/neural/benchmark/FahlmanEncoder.java